# How to clone a repo in teamcity using CommandLine Build step

Tags: version-control, mercurial, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have a project set up in teamcity that needs to clone a repository prior to building the project.
For this, I have added a commandLine  build step, and included the hg command to clone the repo in the custom script field inside teamcity, i.e `hg clone http://path/to/repo/` but I get the following error,
`abort: http authorization required` I have  done some searches and i'm aware that i can include username and password  with the  clone command, however, the syntax for this isn't exactly clear.

Say i have a username- a and a password - b, what would be the correct syntax for running the clone command?

Answer (score 1):

Your commandline should look like this:

`hg clone http://a:b@host/path/to/repo/`

also, to avoid displaying cleartext password/username in build logs and settings in TeamCity, consider using build parameter of ***password*** type. More details can be found in [this documentation page](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Typed+Parameters)